# Examining assembly code mov 0x8(%ebx),%eax mov (%eax),%eax cmp %eax,(%ebx)

Tags: x86

I am working on the final stage of a binary bomb but I am somewhat unsure what these three statements are doing.  Any clarification would be appreciated.

mov    0x8(%ebx),%eax

mov    (%eax),%eax

cmp    %eax,(%ebx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read content of address pointed by EBX+0x8 and store it in EAX register

```
mov 0x8(%ebx),%eax
```

Copy content of address pointed by EAX register to EAX

```
mov (%eax),%eax
```

Compare value in EAX with content of address pointed in EBX register.

```
cmp %eax,(%ebx)
```

so basically it dereference pointer to pointer in address EBX+0x8 and compare its value with value contained in address EBX

Comment: Now if you added a jge statement after those 3 previous statements would you be checking if %eax > (%ebx)?

Comment: jge (jump if equal or greater). so it jumps if %EAX >= (%EBX)